# How to add libbinder, liblog and libutils to CMakeLists.txt and use them in native cpp app?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I saw libbinder, liblog, and libutils in Android.mk as follows:

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libutils libbinder

But my project is using CMakeLists.txt for building. How do I add these shared libraries to my CMakeLists.txt?

Also, are these libraries part of Android NDK and I don't actually need to manually add corresponding .so files to my project? (I am new to it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)